# Akka/play config file for thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, playframework, akka

I have the following example config that works for me

```
blocking-io-dispatcher {
db-backup-context {
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-factor = 3
    core-pool-size-max = 10
  }
}
```

}

I did reading on core pool size, and core pool size max and how it kind of relates to bounded queue. The above is in my application.conf  file for my play web service. 
I followed the below threads/documents

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html - Read the heading `Core and maximum pool sizes`
- http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size

I am still not clear on the following

1. The above config uses bounded queue or un-bounded queue?
2. If the above uses bounded queue, what is the queue size?
3. The value of 3 means that 3 threads will be created each time a request comes to me. After that if 4th request comes and even if bounded queue is not full more threads won't be created until queue is full?
4. How do I specify the queue config in my above config?

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all questions are answered by looking at the akka-actor reference.conf, https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L447

1. & 2. Default is unbounded
2. 3 means that 3 * number of cores on the machine running it, then capped by `core-pool-size-min` and `core-pool-size-max` will be used as `corePoolSize` of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. `corePoolSize` determines how many threads to keep in pool even if they are idle.
3. See `reference.conf` for details around controlling size and type of queue, there are multiple relevant settings.